# How to calculate $ \mathsf{P}(Y < X < Z) $?

Tags: probability

If $ X,Y,Z $ are non-negative random variables whose pdf’s are known, then how do we obtain
$$
\mathsf{P}(Y < X < Z)?
$$
Is it correct to use the Law of Total Expectation twice?

Comment: Yes you may view in this way, and equivalently in general you need to obtain the joint pdfs of these random variables first and do an integration over the region.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully the *joint* probability density function is known.   (If totally independent, marginals will suffice).

$$ \def\d{\,\operatorname{d}\!}\begin{align}\mathsf P(X<Y<Z) ~&=~ \int_0^\infty \int_x^\infty \int_y^\infty f_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z) \d z\d y \d x \\[1ex] &=~ \int_0^\infty\int_0^z\int_0^y f_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z) \d x\d y \d z \end{align}$$

---

But, yes, that is via the Law of Total Expectation, twice, as you suggest.

$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X<Y<Z) ~&=~ \int_0^\infty \mathsf P(x<Y<Z\mid X=x) f_X(x)\d x \\[1ex] &=~ \int_0^\infty \int_x^\infty \mathsf P(y<Z\mid X=x, Y=y)\,f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)\,f_X(x)\d y\d x\\[1ex] &=~ \int_0^\infty\int_x^\infty\int_y^\infty f_{Z\mid X,Y}(z\mid x,y)\,f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)\,f_X(x)\d z\d y\d x \\[1ex] &=~ \int_0^\infty\int_x^\infty\int_y^\infty f_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z)\d z\d y\d x \end{align}$